# loading csv "Could not find installable ISAM"

Tags: excel, vba, csv, oledb

Im building a program in Excel VBA to automate a process and I require data stored in a csv file to be imported. So, I'm trying to use a query table to import specific columns in a csv file.

Im using ADO to interface with the csv file using the Jet Provider OLE DB. In the connection string I have specified the provider, data source, and extended properties. Im using windows xp and office 2003, so my Excel version is 8.0. I specified the provider as Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. My code is pasted below. When the code executes I get the error "Could not find installable ISAM" at the last line that I included in the below code. I cant find anything wrong with the syntax so I was wondering if this error could be because I dont have the correct version of Jet installed? Please see code below. Thanks

```
Sub Excel_QueryTable()

Dim oCn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnString As String
Dim SQL As String

Dim qt As QueryTable

ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\testfile.csv;" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1"","

Set oCn = New ADODB.Connection
oCn.ConnectionString = ConnString
oCn.Open
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\directory\where\csv\file\is\;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
```

I don't think you want to use the "Excel 8.0" portion, but you aren't actually connecting to an Excel worksheet; you're connecting to a text file. Also, you had extra spaces, and connection strings are REALLY picky about those, so I've deleted them.

Note that you can set the delimiter here:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text\Format
```

Mine is currently `CSVDelimited`; other options are `TabDelimited` and `Delimited(;)`

I found this info at: http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile

**-- EDIT --**

Instead of pointing to a specific .csv file, you actually point the data source to a *target directory*. Note my changes above, in the connection string: the filename has been removed, and the path now ends in a `\`.

In order to use this type of data source, you actually need to teach the driver how the file is laid out. You do this [through the use of a schema.ini file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx).

You can create the .ini file one of two ways:

- Manually edit the file by hand, in notepad, using the above link to provide usage.
- Use the tool built into the ODBC Data Source Admin.

In order to use the tool, you need to actually go through the steps of creating a data source. You don't actually need the data source, but as far as I can tell, it's the only way to get to the create schema.ini creation tool.

To get there:

- Go to the ODBC control panel.
- Add a new DSN, type: Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv), click Finish
- On "ODBC Text Setup", uncheck `Use Current Directory` and select the directory where your file lives.
- Click on the options button, and click on the `Define Format` button.
- Click on the file that you want to work with, and click "Guess" to get you started, then refine the data types as necessary.
- When done, click OK, and you should see a `schema.ini` file in the directory where your .csv file is.  Open it in notepad, and make sure it looks right.

The above connection string should now work correctly, using ONLY the directory where your csv lives, not the full path to the .csv.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response but if the "Excel 8.0" portion is not include, when run the program gives an error saying "C:\test file.csv is not a valid path".

Comment: If you are running this VBA inside Excel then it stands to reason that you have Excel installed, and you have the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver installed (which is the ISAM driver it's atlking about in the error). Can you confirm that you are running this in Excel?

Comment: Can you also expand further on what you're trying to do? Whats the source, whats the destination, and what processing is required?

Comment: Yes I am running this inside Excel 2003. I have data in a CSV file stored on a server. I want to pull 4 columns of raw data from this (large) CSV file into my excel work book. The only processing required is for the text to be recognized as comma delimited.

Comment: @user1915992 Take a look at my edit; I completely missed a major component of how to use the driver.